# Laravel Relationships, don't know how to display

Tags: laravel, relationship, voyager

I have two models. Business and City.

Business:

1. id
2. title

-some columns--

7. city_id

City:

1. id
2. name

**How to display the city name, when I get business data to view**

I was able to display cities using the laravel voyager lessons
[image]

[image]

When I want to get it like $business->city_id
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using models, you can create a relationship by adding hasOne or hasMany to your model codes.
When you call it from your controller, you can call the relationship you wrote in your model with the 'with' query.

**Model**

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->hasOne(City::class,'id','cityid');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$business=Business::with('city')->first();
$cityname=$business->city->name;
```

If you don't use model, you can connect with '**join**'

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options. First, you can get city details on the controller:

```
Business::with('city')...;
```

On the blade

```
$business->city->name;
```

Other option fetching it on the blade directly. I don't recommend this because of extra database queries.

```
$business->city()->name;
```